# What was the significance of dinosaur hedge-sculpture made by Edward?

Tags: analysis, edward-scissorhands

Edward Scissorhands's hedge-sculptures always seem meaningful to me, like he had hedge-sculptures in the mansion to signify that he is incomplete and made family sculptures to represent his new foster family, dancing lady for Kim etc. But what was with the dinosaur hedge-sculpture he made in Kim's house? What does it signify?

Comment: An after thought of production.  `Welch said: “We designed them in the art department. We said, ‘Okay, how about one is a dinosaur and one is a turtle and whatever?’ They tended to be fantastical animals.

We designed them and then had them manufactured. They’re light-weight steel armatures wrapped with chicken wire and stuffed with artificial greens. They were light enough to move around.”` I'm trying to find the original source.

Comment: @cde Sounds like an answer when you find the source.

Comment: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/edward-scissorhands-25th-anniversary_us_561c264ae4b0c5a1ce603cd4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @dbugger, I found the source of the quote I found.

To mark the occasion [Of the 25 year Anniversary and re-release of the movie], [The Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/edward-scissorhands-25th-anniversary_us_561c264ae4b0c5a1ce603cd4) hopped on the phone with screenwriter Caroline Thompson and **production designer Bo Welch** to reflect on how the story came to life:

> HP: On Edward’s shrubbery creations:
>
> Welch: “We designed them in the art department. ***We said, ‘Okay, how about one is a dinosaur and one is a tutle and whatever?’ They tended to be fantastical animals.*** We designed them and then had them manufactured. They’re light-weight steel armitures wrapped with chicken wire and stuffed with artificial greens. They were light enough to move around.”

While undoubtedly the storyboards called for something, the specific animals are an after though of production, a spitballed selection between the props masters.

The garden sculptures are not mentioned in the script by name. The Ice Sculpture later in the film is also not detailed in the script, just a generic ice mass sculpture:

```
        (Kim goes out into the garden and 
        sees Edward sculpture an ice mass. 
        When he sculptures it, snowflakes 
        begin to fall, and Kim dances in 
        the snow. After he finishes it, he 
        cuts her hand by accident. Then Jim 
        shows up.)
```

#### ***In any case***

We cannot infer an in-universe meaning to the sculptures other than **"Edward thought they were nice"** or **"Edward thought the people would think they were nice"**. He obviously knows enough to create a demon to scare the bible-thumper, so he has enough social skills to understand how they would appear.